# CSS+JS: webkit-calc or alternative method to animate things in a responsive environment

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

I'm coding a web app with PhoneGap for smartphones so I need to have responsive CSS to adapt to the various width, but most important in my case, **heights**

So I have a main `#wrapper` with style `height:100%` and I want to tap a button and slide it up all the way to the top, but 50px.

If I would know the exact height of the screen, let's assume 480px, I would simply do `translateY(-430px)`, done.

I tried using `webkit-calc`, but beside it's supported only by few browser, I got crashes everytime I use it. dunno why.

What's the best practice to solve this simple problem?

Comment: I think that [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: calc is very supported these days... even old old ie can use expression(), which is basically the same thing for the purpose described...